# Convert Excel rows to PDF pages using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in Excel with student names and their marks.
I want to export the data to PDF using VBA macro where each student details appear on a different PDF page. So if there are 20 students then there will be 20 pages in single PDF. Each student name will form heading of the PDF page and their marks will appear in a table below the heading.

I have a table like this in Excel

```
student name  -  erp  -    science marks        -geography marks
                           test1  test2          test1  test2  test3
peter         -  12        15      9.5           15      7      11
jack          -  13        16      11            10      9      13
```

How can I export this data in a PDF like `student.pdf`, where page1 will have peter name as heading and the sum of his science marks and geography marks. Similarly, page2 will have jack's name and sum of his marks. How can I do that?

Also, the number of students is dynamic. So I have to count the number of students and that will be the count of my PDF. How do I do that?

code so far

```
Sub convertTopdf()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

ChDir "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\task_excel\POD.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With ws
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

MsgBox "The last row which has data in Col A of Sheet1 is " & lastRow

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site; what is your question? To start with, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Moosli - the OP doesn't know what to try, that is why he is asking.

Comment: Autofilter would be the best bet. Don't know your layout situation so really can't come up with an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @MS123 . It would be helpful if you edited your post to include the code, it doesn't format very nicely in comments. Are you able to print to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

If you print multiple selected ranges, then each range will be printed to a different page. If you were printing multiple areas on a single page, this would be as simple as:

```
Range("Sheet1!C5:D6,Sheet1!D13:E14").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
```

So if you want each row to be printed to a different page, just use a FOR loop to define the ranges and print the sheet like this...

```
myrange = "A1:C1"
lastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For myRow = 2 To lastRow
   myrange = myrange & ",A" & myRow & ":C" & myRow
Next
Range(myrange).Select
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

This will open a print dialog, and you can select the printer of your choice (including PDF). I assume that you have the ability to print to PDF in some way - if you have Excel 2010, for example, you can simply select "Adobe PDF" as your printer.

Be sure to select "print selection" and not the entire worksheet :)

Comment: eddy i just dont want to print my data, i want to sum the marks also. The data is dynamic, so i cant hardcode the ranges

Comment: my pdf will be like                                                                                           PETER                                                                                                                       24.5  Science                                                                                                         33     Geography

Comment: @MS123 I see you've changed your question somewhat. OK.. My answer gives you a very clear way to print each row of your worksheet onto a separate page, which was your original question. Your next step is to add those totals - you can't print something that isn't there. I suggest you use a clean worksheet, and have your macro write the names & totals to it, then print it as laid out above.